# Asset Browser broke all my blend files

Tags: blend-files, asset-browser, accessibility

I am having real trouble with Blender 3.3 LTS asset Library.

Now that the asset library came out I thought to give it a shot and put all my assets into that library, which took some days.
Now that I am done and can pull all my asets from the library into my blendfiles, which is great, here comes the problem.
I can not open any of the blendfiles that contain any assets anymore, none of them.

Every single blend file that I´ve put into my asset library folder is now broken and can´t be opened. This just killed 10 years if work within 2-3 days, which is really not great! I mean, I can still access the assets via the asset browser, but the blend files seem to be corrupted or whatever happened. I am really afraid of losing all my work!

At first I´ve created a new path for my library and File Paths like you can see in this image: [image: FilePathBlenderSettings]

Then I moved my blend files into that folder, opened them one by one and set up the assets via "Object/Asset/Mark as Asset" and sorted them into catalogs before I moved on to the next file.
After some files I decided to setup my startup file to always show the asset-browser when launching blender, which I think leads to the problem, will come to that later.

After I was done I opened a new blend file and started placing some assets, realizing that some of them are too big in scale.
Then I wanted to open that file via right clicking the asset in the browser: "Open Blend File". Which did not work. Than I navigated to the folder where the file is and tried to open it via double click, doesn't work either, I also tried an older blender version, nothing.

Then I tried opening other blendfiles via the asset browser, realizing that most of them don´t open, but some do.

Then I wanted to open a new empty blendfile, realizing that blender does also crash immediately now with a fresh file.

At first I was confused, then I came to the idea that it could be the asset-browser open at startup, so I opened another blendfile that does not have the asset-browser open and it worked.

So I deleted all the assets in it and setup a new startup file without the asset-browser open and blender started again when opening it without a file.

But the blend files with asset libraries in it still remain broken.

To be clear, Blender does not hang, it immediately crashes, not file I´m in, but the file I want to open which contains assets.

Some images:

Asset Library (this blendfile can not be opened):  [image: Screenshot]
Asset Library (this can be opened):  [image: Screenshot]

Broken Blendfile: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uQyHx88KpIK8kc8LIUBGO_guZHdzCWLV/view?usp=sharing

And some minutes after I´ve written all this I did find a solution to fix this.
Just delete your startup.blend file under: `AppData/Roaming/Blender/YourBlenderVersion/config`

Comment: Hello, could you describe how you open the files with your assets ? Are they by any chance on a network drive ? Can you share an example file for us to try out ? Also, how is your library structured ? Can you share a screenshot of your asset browser interface ?

Comment: Hey ! Just as a heads-up you can edit your question to add this information, the comment section is not well suited for long swathes of text :) Does Blender crash completely and return to desktop, or does it hang up seemingly indefinitely ? If it's the latter, I think you're just a victim of the asset browser not being optimised at all for large asset databases, so it takes a very long time to load the asset information. Try to let it load for several minutes and see if it loads. Otherwise you can try to move your whole database to another folder (or rename it) and see if the files load

Comment: Blender crashes immediatly
I will edit my question at the end to summerize everything, thank you for the info :)

Comment: @André Hi, thanks for the post. While answering your own question is possible and even encouraged when you find a solution , it should be done respecting the site structure. Could you break this up into two posts, while keeping the solution written as separate answer in the proper section below? Maybe add a short description of the steps involved See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Also, instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Answer (score 0):

I´ve found a solution.
Just delete your startup.blend file under AppData/Roaming/Blender/YourBlenderVersion/config